# text field become Empty when table View Scrolled Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

there is a table View Inside VC2 to Modify or add Contact into phone . **the problem it is text fields become blank in Sections when table view scrolled** . i found a way to fix this Problem But i cant handle it Properly .

Model :

```
class ContactModel : NSObject {
    var identifier : String!
    var thumbnailImageData : UIImage?
    var givenName : String!
    var familyName : String!
    var phoneNumbers : [String]!
    var emailAddresses : [String]!

    override init() {
        self.phoneNumbers = []
        self.emailAddresses = []
        super.init()
    }
```

VC2 :

```
        var contactModel = ContactModel()

        @IBOutlet weak var tvInsert: UITableView!

           override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
        }

            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

                if indexPath.section == 0 {
                    let cell0 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InsertTableCell0") as! InsertTableCell0
                    cell0.txtFirstName.text = self.contactModel.givenName
                    cell0.txtLastName.text = self.contactModel.familyName
                    return cell0
                }else if indexPath.section == 1 {
                    let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InsertTableCell1") as! InsertTableCell1
                    cell1.btnDelete.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteRowDate(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                    cell1.txtPhoneNumber.placeholder = "Phone Number"
                    cell1.txtPhoneNumber.text = contactModel.phoneNumbers[indexPath.row]
// here i get textField tag 
                    cell1.txtPhoneNumber.tag = indexPath.row
                    cell1.txtPhoneNumber.delegate = self
                    return cell1
                }else {
                    let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InsertTableCell2") as! InsertTableCell2
                    cell2.btnEmail.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteRowDate(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                    cell2.txtEmail.placeholder = "Email"
                    cell2.txtEmail.text = contactModel.emailAddresses[indexPath.row]
                    return cell2

                }
            }

       func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

            let index = IndexPath(row: textField.tag, section: 1)
            let cell = tvInsert.cellForRow(at: index) as? InsertTableCell1
            let pointInTable = cell?.txtPhoneNumber.convert(textField.bounds.origin, to: self.tvInsert)
            let textFieldIndexPath = self.tvInsert.indexPathForRow(at: pointInTable!)
            print(textFieldIndexPath)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create model of your all field you need and set array as blank as follow.

```
var dict:[String:Any] = [:]
    dict["description"] = ""
    arrGetEducationList.append(EducationDetailsArrModel(JSON: dict)!)
    self.tblEducation.reloadData()
```

After in you tableview cell set model data like that

```
    let edu = self.arrGetEducationList[indexPath.row]
    cell.txtSchool.text = edu.edu_institute_name
```

After that create delegate methods for textfield

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let pointInTable = textField.convert(textField.bounds.origin, to: self.tblEducation)
    let IndexPath = self.tblEducation.indexPathForRow(at: pointInTable)
    if let cell = tblEducation.cellForRow(at: IndexPath!) as? AddEducationCell1 {

        if cell.txtSchool == textField{
            arrGetEducationList[(IndexPath?.row)!].edu_institute_name = textField.text!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx Its Work Well

Answer (score 0):

Your text fields are obviously reused.
So, use temporary storage in order to save the temporary content. 
e.g, you can use

```
yourTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChanged(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

and to catch:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField){

 storage[textField.tag] = textField.text
}
let storage = [Int: String]()


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let tag = tagFromIndexPath(indexPath)
textField.text = storage[tag]
}
```

Comment: should i use : yourTextField.addTarget.... into viewDidLoad or some where else ? and what is tagFromIndexPath in cellForRow . ?

Answer (score 0):

you must have to set textfield's value in your model also.
in `textFieldDidEndEditing` this method.

Answer (score 0):

The `UITextField`s will be get empty for sure, hence you did not update your `contactModel` with the data typed into that `UITextField`. Your method `textFieldDidEndEditing` looks Error prone, however in the end you need to update all needed properties of `contactModel` within that method.

e.g.:

```
contactModel.givenName = textField.text
```